# MariaDB, StoredProcedure no se ejecuta completo..!

Tags: stored-procedure, mariadb

tengo el siguiente codigo, pero no hace el update a la tabla, ejecuta el SELECT y luego ejecuta el INSERT, pero ya no ejecuta el UPDATE para otros campos..

[image: Este es el query]

Comment: Lectura altamente sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Especialmente punto 2. Detalla a tal nivel que cualquier persona en el sitio podría reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.

Comment: ¡No ignores los comentarios! Además, [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976) . El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Asunto Resuelto**

Resulta que el update no hacia la operacion porque en algunas columnas habia valores nulos, entonces lo que hice fue pasar esos nulos a ceros, y el update ya funciono perfectamente